# (glsl/hlsl) Integrating over 1 dimension of a 2D texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, direct3d, hlsl

### My Problem:

I need a shader to perform a kind-of cumulative sum across each row of a 2D texture. For instance, pixel [3,3] of the new texture should be the sum of pixels [1,3], [2,3] and [3,3] of the source texture. In other words, numerical integration.

My texture size will probably end up being between 64x64 and 256x256 texels depending on performance, so doing a brute-force per-pixel sum is probably out of the question.

Unfortunately **I** can't use automatic mipmap generation on a 1D texture array as I'm not actually doing *regular* addition. However, I should *probably* be able to adapt a manual solution that does use addition.

NOTE: I'm working with both GLSL and HLSL but they seem almost entirely feature-compatible.

---

### Idea so far:

My current idea is to perform a kind-of manual 1d mipmap in a pixel-shader (using non-interpolated texel fetches), but possibly reducing size by a factor of 4 or 8 per mipmap-level instead of just 2.

For example:

1. Original (Sum-0). [64x64].
2. Sum-1. [64x64] -> [16x64].
3. Sum-2. [16x64] -> [4x64].
4. Sum-3. [4x64] -> [1x64]. (Totals of each entire row).

Once this is done, I descend through the mipmap levels (beginning with smallest), adding the accumulated sum of the previous level (adjusting for size and offset by 1) to the sum of the previous texels in the same row segment, and placing in a new texture.

```
level-N-accum[(a*width)+b,y] =
  level-N+1-accum[a-1,y]
    +
  sum(first b pixels starting from level-N-sum[a*width,y])
```

For example:

1. Accum-2. [4x64] = (Sum-2 + Sum-3)
2. Accum-1. [16x64] = (Sum-1 + Accum-2)
3. Result (Accum-0). [64x64] = (Sum-0 + Accum-1)

This gives me an O(ln(X)) per-pixel complexity.

---

### My Questions:

1. Is this the right way to go or is there a better way?
2. Would I be better off using compute (haven't used that yet)?

Comment: *"...doing a brute-force per-pixel sum is probably out of the question..."* Why is this out of the question? GPUs are great at doing this kind of thing.

Comment: What I meant by that was that each pixel would sum all the pixels before it, meaning pixel[256,N] would need to fetch and add 256 values. Overall, that means a 256x256 texture would need to do ~((256^3)/2) samples (=~8 million). My way currently does (256x256xlog2(256))/log2(width) = ~262144 samples.

Comment: That's pretty similar to "prefix sum" or "scan".  There are plenty of established GPU-based algorithms for this that should be easy to adapt to operate on multiple rows simultaneously, and maintaining intermediate values (e.g. [this one](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html)).  If your texture has more than 512 rows though, you'll get enough parallelism that the brute-force option might actually be better.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look into it - first I've got to implement compute on glsl/hlsl.

Comment: Perhaps I misused the term brute force. I meant having every pixel do its own naive sum of all the pixels before it, independently, meaning that, for every row of width N texels there would need to be approx N*N*0.5 texel lookups. I don't think that's what you mean, though.

Comment: I was saying only do one invocation per row and write to multiple locations in a RWTexture2D. This way there are N texel lookups and N writes.  That's a lot of work per invocation but if you have a lot of them, you'll still get enough parallelism that it might be worth it.  You'd probably want to use compute though since a 1x512 draw call is kind of weird and might cause things to run more slowly than they need to (e.g. if it pads out to 2 pixels to run helper quads, and the scheduler isn't able to suppress them).

Comment: The scan & prefix sum algorithms are optimized for a single stream with a lot of elements, not multiple independent streams with relatively few.  Depending on the number of rows, a hybrid approach between the "brute force" method I described, and the scan methods, might be best.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper called ['Fast Summed-Area Table Generation and its Applications' by J. Hensley, T. Scheuermann, G. Coombe, M. Singh, and Anselmo Lastra.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.8836&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
Did you try their approach?